# How does the following code work on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

In one of Philip Lackner's tutorial, he is making the network call and UI changes like following:

```
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        binding.progressBar.isVisible = true
        val response = try {
            RetrofitInstance.api.getTodos()
        } catch(e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException, you might not have internet connection")
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
            return@launchWhenCreated
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "HttpException, unexpected response")
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
            return@launchWhenCreated
        }
        if(response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
            todoAdapter.todos = response.body()!!
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response not successful")
        }
        binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
    }
```

Here is the pointer to his code: https://github.com/philipplackner/RetrofitCrashCourse/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/plcoding/retrofitcrashcourse/MainActivity.kt

lifecycleScope is by default tied to main thread which means unless we change the scope, the retrofit network call in the above code is going to be run on main thread.

Is this statement correct, if not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complicated, but I'll try to explain it based on what I've found out during my spelunking in the Retrofit code.

**Yes**, you are indeed running the call `RetrofitInstance.api.getTodos()` on the main dispatcher (implicitly via `lifecycleScope`), but...

**No**, you aren't running it on the main thread. Under the hood, suspend functions in Retrofit are implemented by using a combination of a `suspendCancellableCoroutine` and `enqueue(...)` [as seen in the source code itself](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/KotlinExtensions.kt#L93-L108):

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Call<T>.awaitResponse(): Response<T> {
  return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
      cancel()
    }
    enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
      override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
        continuation.resume(response)
      }

      override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
        continuation.resumeWithException(t)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

With that in mind, `enqueue(...)` will eventually (somewhere down the rabbit hole) do the actual network request on a another executor, and thus it's doesn't cause any `NetworkOnMainThread` violations when you call it from the main dispatcher. Why? Well, it doesn't actually do any network calls on the main thread, per se.

Hope that clarifies it a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Short explanation: You never have to worry about what thread or dispatcher you’re on when calling a suspend function, because a proper suspend function doesn’t block. If it needs a specific dispatcher, it internally delegates to it using `withContext`. In the case of Retrofit, it doesn’t use a dispatcher at all—it uses Retrofit’s own thread pool and suspends using `suspendCancellableCoroutine`.

Any library designed by competent Kotlin users will have suspend functions that follow this same convention. Suspend functions never block.